# What does closures return in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, closures

I've come across a very interesting - yet confusing - code snippet and had hard time to understand what exactly does it return it.

```js
// Create a data point generator.
var getDataPoint = (function() {
  var _x = -1;
  var _max = _data.length;

  return function() {
    _x = (_x + 1) % _max;
    return {
      x: Date.now(),
      y: _data[_x]
    };
  };
})();

var heartRate = 60; // bpm
var interval = 60 * 1000 / (_data.length * heartRate);

// Generate a new data point based on the heart rate.
setInterval(function() {
  $('.jke-ecgChart').ecgChart('addDataPoint', getDataPoint());
}, interval);
```

Now I have a very basic understanding of closures and how they work, for example, they're scope within outer functions.

But what confused me more is this specific line:

`$('.jke-ecgChart').ecgChart('addDataPoint', getDataPoint());`

What will `getDataPoint()` return? A function or {x, y}?

What if I wanted to return {x, y} instead of the function?

Thanks

Comment: It returns a function

Comment: Why do you think `return function() {...};` wouldn't return a function? If you want to return a value, just return the value.

Comment: I still do believe it should return function, but in the console for some reason, it returns an array of scopes. @SLaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `getDataPoint` is resolved to be a value returned by an `immediately invoked function` in the first line. hence getDataPoint stores reference to a function returned at `line 4`. hence, when you call it at `$('.jke-ecgChart').ecgChart('addDataPoint', getDataPoint())`, the function at line 4 will be called, which will return {x, y}, not a function. You can see the similar example in the code below, I have used some constants in it, just to be able to log the output.

```js
// Create a data point generator.
var getDataPoint = (function() {
  var _x = -1;
  var _max = 6;

  return function() {
    _x = (_x + 1) % _max;
    return {
      x: Date.now(),
      y: _x
    };
  };
})();

var heartRate = 60; // bpm
var interval = 1000;

// Generate a new data point based on the heart rate.
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(getDataPoint());
}, interval);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Appreciate it :)